# Synchronous mysql in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I know that node.js is event driven and I should do this async but i can't find in my mind a way to do it.

so, i have this

```
var querystr = "SELECT * FROM groups";
    var result = "";
    dbClient.query(querystr, function (err, res, fields) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        for(var i in res) {
            result = result + "@" +res[i].name + " =";
            for (var j in res[i].members.split(",")) {
                var memberquery;
                if (j.substr(0,1) == "@") {
                    memberquery = "SELECT name FROM groups WHERE id = "+j.substr(1, j.length-1);
                } else {
                    memberquery = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id= "+j;
                }
                dbClient.query(memberquery, function(err, memres, fields) {
                    var membername = "";
                    if (typeof memres[0].username == "undefined") {
                        membername = "@"+memres[0].name;
                    } else {
                        membername = memres[0].username;
                    }
                    result = result + " " + membername; 
                });

            }
            result = result + "\n"; 
        }
    });
```

The issue that makes it sync is the for inside.
basically i'm generating a document in the result variable where i check the groups and tell the members so the expected output is

```
Group1 = member, member
Group2 = member, member
```

Comment: Couple of quick asides: If you did a first pass of your first query results, and loop into the members on a second pass, you could avoid the SELECT name FROM groups queries. Additionally, if your DB was normalized properly, you could imagine a single query doing all that table-matching work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use a pattern like the one below for this type of problem. In a nutshell: get a list of things then call a function to handle the list; that function calls itself until the list is completed; gather up the results as you go in an accumulator; when the list is empty, return whatever you've accumulated through the callback. It's just another way of accomplishing what @Andrey Sidorov demonstrated in his response.

```
//cb is (err, res) 
function getData(cb){
  var querystr = "SELECT * FROM groups";
  var result = "";

  dbClient.query(querystr, function (err, res, fields) {
      if (err)
          cb(err);
      else {
        var groups = [];
        for (var ndx in res)
          groups = groups.concat(res[ndx].members.split(","));

        getMembers(groups, [], cb);
      }
  });
}

function getMembers(members, sofar, cb){
  var member = members.shift();

  if (!member)
    cb(null, sofar);
  else {
    var memberquery;
    var params;

    if (member.substr(0,1) == "@") {
        memberquery = "SELECT name FROM groups WHERE id = ?";
        params = [member.substr(1, member.length-1)];
    } else {
        memberquery = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = ?";
        params = [member];
    }

    dbClient.query(memberquery, params, function(err, res) {
      if (err)
        cb(err);
      else {
        var membername = "";
        if (typeof res[0].username == "undefined") {
            membername = "@" + res[0].name;
        } else {
            membername = res[0].username;
        }

        sofar.push(membername);

        getMembers(members, sofar, cb);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: @Andrey true, though node-mysql queues them anyway and only issues the next when the previous has completed  -- so I don't think there's really much difference in that respect. But, you're right, that if you used some pool and could issue the queries simultaneously to mysql, you'd get some parallelization.

Comment: thanks @Andrey and @Geoff, I thought I deleted the question since I came with a solution thanks to async.js (well, portion of it). I'm using an approach like Geoff (in fact now i have a function called getMembers) but i'll take a look to the other one since I'm not expecting a response to output, this can be perfectly async

Comment: if you are using one connection the queries are serialized even if you expect no output. The only way to execute queries in parallel is to execute them in separate connections (probably using connections pool)

Answer (score 1):

```
function do_queries( resultCallback )
{
    var querystr = "SELECT * FROM groups";
    var result = "";
    var num_queries_left = 0;
    dbClient.query(querystr, function (err, res, fields) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        // calculate number of invocations of second sub-query
        for(var i in res)
            num_queries_left += res[i].members.split(",").length;

        for(var i in res) {
            result = result + "@" +res[i].name + " =";                 
            for (var j in res[i].members.split(",")) {
                var memberquery;
                if (j.substr(0,1) == "@") {
                    memberquery = "SELECT name FROM groups WHERE id = "+j.substr(1, j.length-1);
                } else {
                    memberquery = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id= "+j;
                }
                dbClient.query(memberquery, function(err, memres, fields) {
                    var membername = "";
                    if (typeof memres[0].username == "undefined") {
                        membername = "@"+memres[0].name;
                    } else {
                        membername = memres[0].username;
                    }
                    result = result + " " + membername;
                    num_queries_left--;
                    if (num_queries_left == 0)
                    {
                        resultCallback(result);
                        return;
                    } 
                });

            }
            result = result + "\n"; 
        }
    });
}


do_queries( function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```