# Node.js MYSQL to run each Queries sequencially after previous one is done?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I'm using Javascript MYSQL Library from Node.js and then i have multiple queries to run in loop. But when i run the loop, `the loop` always reach to end (done) suddenly while the Queries it started are still processing. So how do i keep the loop to wait each Query til done and then continue normally?

My code is:

```
function startHere() {
    console.log("-- START --");
    for (i=1; i < 6; i++) {
        dbInsert(i);
    }
    console.log("-- END --");
}
function dbInsert(id) {
    connection.query (
        'INSERT INTO table SET data=?',
        [id],
        function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
            if (results.length > 0) {
                console.log(id+" RECORDS ADDED!");
            }
        }
    );
}
startHere();
```

When i run it, it always returns like:

```
-- START --
-- END --
1 RECORDS ADDED!
2 RECORDS ADDED!
3 RECORDS ADDED!
4 RECORDS ADDED!
5 RECORDS ADDED!
```

It means, the loop doesn't wait the end of the queries it started.
How can i detect the end-point of the queries and make it work?

Comment: I think this is a duplication to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638646/synchronous-mysql-in-node-js

Comment: Firstly, get more familiar with what `asynchronous` stands for (Google is your friend on this one). Secondly, checkout [this page](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Answer (score 0):

Your selectCb method is not being called synchronously, so your loop is effectively firing off each call and then returning.

You can either check the docs for a synchronous version of that connection.query method, or you will need to create a callback to print the end message after all your inserts have fired.

Answer (score 0):

[`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) should work for you

```
async.series([
    function(){ ... },
    function(){ ... }
]);
```

See https://github.com/caolan/async#series